# Execute parser methods wihout the main method

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, hash, nlp

When I try to invoke parserAction()  method  inside an another servlet class  I'm getting a blank array. I cant print the nouns inside my servlet. But inside this class with the MAIN METHOD noun array is printing correctly. What is the reason for this ?

```
    package com.books.servlet;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ParserAction;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;

public class ParserTest {



    public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();


    public String line = "I need the java book";



    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP")
                || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
            nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
            // System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
        }

        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
            getNounPhrases(child);

        }
    }

    public  void parserAction() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
        Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
        for (Parse p : topParses) {
            // p.show();
            getNounPhrases(p);
        }
    }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          new ParserTest().parserAction();
          System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+nounPhrases);

         }




    }
```

Below is my sample servlet class. It shows me a blank array with []

```
    public class test extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 .......
 .......
 .......
ParserTest pt = new ParserTest();
 pt.parserAction();

 System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+pt.nounPhrases);
 System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+ParserTest.nounPhrases);
}
}
```

Here I need to extract nouns without executing a main method. Since I'm developing a web application. I need to show these extracted nouns inside one of my servlet class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write what you want in the response, for example by doing:

```
response.getWriter().println("Whatever you want to write in the response");
```

But first I would suggest to read some good Java books as your code is not very good, also servlets are an old way of doing Java web application, nowadays people use other technologies, like templates using JSP or JSF, JAX-RS for REST applications, JAX-WS for SOAP applications, ...

Comment: it gives me the output [] only...why that parser method is not executing ?  when I try it with a main method it works fine...but inside servlet it is not executing

Comment: Try and debug your code, there is no way I can guess whatever those ParserTool / ParserModel are doing. I do have a guess that you don't find the file "en-parser-chunking.bin" because when you launch your web application using a container the current directory is different and that your code doesn't crash in this case like it probably should.